# how can i read an image from postgresql database table and use it in face_recognition function in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is models.py

```
class GeeksModel(models.Model): 
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "media/") 

def __str__(self): 
    return self.title
```

This is the views.py function

```
images = GeeksModels.objects.all()
connection = psycopg2.connect(user ='#####' , 
                                 password = '#####',
                                  host = 'localhost',
                                  port='5432',
                                  database='######')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "select img from authen_geeksmodel"
cursor.execute(query)
images = cursor.fetchall()

for img in images:
    
    face_2_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_2_image)[0]

    check=face_recognition.compare_faces([face_1_face_encoding] , face_encodings)
```

The error it shows that it cannot read the images it must be in 8bit or RGB

SO HOW CAN I READ THE IMAGES FROM MY DATABASE AND THEN USE THAT IMAGE IN MY FACE_RECOGNITION FUNCTION

The main doubt I have how cant i convert the fetched image itno a readable  image format

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to make PostgreSQL connections if you are using Django, please read or check some Django views and how to make PostgreSQL configurations.

In Django images does not save on DB. Only their names recorded. The image is putting on file system. For more [check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/).

```
for img in images:
    # img is an instance of GeeksModel which has {pk, id, title, img} fields
    # img.img will give you image' name like 'media/my_image.png'(media comes from 'upload_to' param on ImageField)
    # img.img.path will give you '/home/my_project/uploads/media/my_image.png' if MEDIA_ROOT='/home/my_project/uploads' on settings.py 
    face_2_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img.img.path) # here should be like this
```

Comment: I tried this and in the second line of code is used                                              
 face_encodings = face_recognition(face_2_image)                                                                         This line shows the error that list index out of range                                                                           
 Then i tried to open image using PIL's Image.open(img.img.path)  It shows the error that "Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image."

Comment: can somehow i can get the relative path of the image because that works for me